# Flex 4 Slider with two thumbs

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

anybody know how to make a custom hslider in Flex 4 (spark) with two thumbs? Since Flex 4 the thumbcount property of the slider component isn't longer available (at the mx component it was easily to set). I have to style the track and the thumbs.

A tutorial would be nice.

thx,
tux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a full tutorial for you but here are the first few steps in creating a custom hslider component. Hope it helps.

Start by looking at the hslider skin which is made up of 2 parts, a thumb and a track:

```
<s:Button id="track" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="33" width="100"
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin" />
<s:Button id="thumb" top="0" bottom="0" width="11" height="11" 
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin" />
```

Now, create a new skin except give it two buttons:

```
<s:Button id="track" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minWidth="33" width="100"
                  skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin" />
<s:Button id="thumb" top="0" bottom="0" width="11" height="11" 
                  skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin" />
<s:Button id="thumb2" top="0" bottom="0" width="11" height="11" 
                  skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin" />
```

Create a new component that extends HSlider and call it something like MultiButtonSlider. Override the partAdded() function and grab a reference to thumb2 when its added.

```
override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void{
if(partName == "thumb2"){
    thumb2 = instance as Button;
}
}
```

Hope this starts you off in the right direction. Don't forget to set the MultiButtonSlider.skinClass = "YourNewSkin"

Next steps would be to make it draggable and convert its point to a value. See the HSlider.pointToValue() function.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick Mowrer has a free one over on GitHub: https://github.com/pmowrer/spark-components

I was able to use it without much of a problem in a recent project.  The component doesn't expose (to MXML) all the properties that the Spark one does (for example, [dataTipFormatFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SliderBase.html#dataTipFormatFunction) is absent), but one can still access and customize them through custom skinning.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm using the mx component instead of the sparks compontent for now.

```
<mx:HSlider x="46" y="358" minimum="1" maximum="600" snapInterval="1"
thumbCount="2" values="[1,600]" id="hsTiming" height="23" width="618" 
change="hsTiming_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this topic (AS3)

[Flash Range Slider Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003598/flash-range-slider-component)

Answer (score 1):

To supplement shi11i's answer, who put me on the right track, here is the full code :

```
package test.components
```

{

```
import flash.geom.Point;

import spark.components.Button;
import spark.components.Group;
import spark.components.HSlider;


public class HSliderTwoThumbs extends HSlider
{
    private var _value2:Number;

    [Bindable]
    public function get value2():Number
    {
        return _value2;
    }

    public function set value2(value:Number):void
    {
        _value2=value;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }


    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var thumb2:Button;

    public function HSliderTwoThumbs()
    {
        super();
        //this.setStyle("skinClass", "HRangeSliderSkin");
    }

    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
    {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);
    }


    override protected function updateSkinDisplayList():void
    {
        super.updateSkinDisplayList();

        if (!thumb2 || !track || !rangeDisplay)
            return;

        var thumbRange:Number=track.getLayoutBoundsWidth() - thumb2.getLayoutBoundsWidth();
        var range:Number=maximum - minimum;

        // calculate new thumb position.
        var thumbPosTrackX:Number=(range > 0) ? ((value2 - minimum) / range) * thumbRange : 0;
        // convert to parent's coordinates.
        var thumbPos:Point=track.localToGlobal(new Point(thumbPosTrackX, 0));
        var thumbPosParentX:Number=thumb2.parent.globalToLocal(thumbPos).x; //- distanceToSecondThumb

        thumb2.setLayoutBoundsPosition(Math.round(thumbPosParentX), thumb2.getLayoutBoundsY());

    }

}}
```

And here is how to use it :

```
    <components:HSliderTwoThumbs id="sliderTwoThumbs"                                                skinClass="test.skins.HRangeSliderSkin"
width="300"
minimum="0"
maximum="300"
value="150"
value2="100"

/>
```

Hope this helps.

**Note** : In my case I did not handle the draggability of the second cursor, as I did not not need it (it was a "read-only" component).  I would be interested in seeing how you handle it, though.